# I need this diamond shape pattern in R

Tags: r

```
                                   *
                                  * *
                                 * * *
                                * * * *
                               * * * * *
                                * * * *
                                 * * *
                                  * *
                                   *
```

This is my code so far, but it throws an error:

> Error in " " * (rows - i - 1) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
>   Calls: pyramid -> print
>   Execution halted

```
#R version 3
pyramid<-function(rows){for (i in rows){print(" "*(rows-i-1)+"*"*(i+1))}
for(j in (rows-1|0|-1)){print(" "*(rows-j)+"*"*(j))}}
rows<-5
pyramid(rows)
```

Comment: Your code is trying to multiply a character (`" "`) by an integer, hence the error "non-numeric argument to binary operator".

Comment: This does not seem to be valid/sensible R code. For example: What are you trying to do with `(rows-1|0|-1)`?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Diamond creator +](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162930)

Answer (score 1):

**You can find plenty of (pseudo-code) examples on the net. That should've been your first approach towards solving your problem. SO is not a free code writing service, and you'll get a much more positive response if you demonstrate a genuine attempt at solving the problem yourself.**

That aside, here is a "crude" R implementation of a code example I found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-print-diamond-shape/). The code can and probably should be "R-ified", and I encourage you to spend some time doing so. I promise that you'll learn a lot. For example, it should be possible to replace most (all?) explicit `for` loops by making use of vectorised functions.

```
diamond <- function(max) {

    # Upper triangle
    space <- max - 1
    for (i in 0:(max - 1)) {
        for (j in 0:space) cat(" ")
        for (j in 0:i) cat("* ")
        cat("\n")
        space <- space - 1
    }

    # Lower triangle
    space = 1;
    for (i in (max - 1):1) {
        for (j in 0:space) cat(" ")
        for (j in 0:(i - 1)) cat("* ")
        cat("\n")
        space <- space + 1
    }
}
diamond(5)
#    *
#   * *
#  * * *
# * * * *
#* * * * *
# * * * *
#  * * *
#   * *
#    *
```